# Google tag manager fires on submit form two times

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I created custom HTML tag in GTM , which runs when Model DOM is ready. It should work when form is submited, but it fires two times.

What can be the problem?

```
<script>
$('.form_check'). submit(function(){
  gtag('event', 'send',  {'event_category': 'form', 'eventAction': 'send'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: First, is your end goal to send the event to Google Analytics?  Second, is there a reason that you're using custom HTML and not setting up a form submission trigger in GTM?

Comment: The script looks fine. Is there any other JS scripts which will trigger form submissions?

Comment: @Angelzzz I am seeing the same issue - did you come to a resolution?